# how to plot a vector in R?

Tags: r

I would like to plot the old and the new vector on a diagram. Do I need to use par function or what else?

```
    programme<-function(a,old_vector){
#there would be two input: V(the vector to be rotated), a(the angle of rotation)

    old_vector=matrix(c(cos(a),sin(a),sin(a),cos(a)),nrow=2)
#the matrix is 2*2 matrix

    rotated_vector=old vector%*%old_vector
#To rotate a vector (,) widdershins (anticlockwise) by  radians,

    return(rotated_vector)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your rotation function need a little edit so I edit that code.

```
programme<-function(a,old_vector){
 
  
  rotate_matrix <- matrix(c(cos(a),sin(a),-sin(a),cos(a)),nrow=2)
 
  
  rotated_vector <- rotate_matrix %*% (old_vector)
 
  
  rotated_vector
}
programme(pi/3, c(1,0))
          [,1]
[1,] 0.5000000
[2,] 0.8660254
```

To plot those two vectors(original, rotated), try this function

```
programme_plot<-function(a,old_vector){
 
  
  rotate_matrix <- matrix(c(cos(a),sin(a),-sin(a),cos(a)),nrow=2)
 
  
  rotated_vector <-  as.vector(t(rotate_matrix %*% (old_vector)))
 
  dummy1 <- rbind(c(0,0), old_vector)
  dummy2 <- rbind(c(0,0), rotated_vector)
  {plot(c(0, old_vector[1]), c(0, old_vector[2]), type="l", 
        xlim = c(min(0,old_vector[1], rotated_vector[1]),max(0,old_vector[1], rotated_vector[1])),
        ylim = c(min(0,old_vector[2], rotated_vector[2]),max(0,old_vector[2], rotated_vector[2])),
        xlab = "X", ylab = "y")
  lines(c(0, rotated_vector[1]), c(0, rotated_vector[2]), type="l", col = "red")}
  
}
programme_plot(pi/3, c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: what if I do not use %>% function, can i get so?

Comment: @itchycat You can just change that line to `rotated_vector <-  as.vector(t(rotate_matrix %*% (old_vector)))`. I edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

There is next to nothing about plotting in your code so I asume this is a a question about how to draw arrows in base plots.

Base graphics have a function `arrows` but first you must draw a coordinate system as, e.g,

```
# make a playfield
plot(NA, xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1))
```

This command should be altered to define x- and y-limits, lable axes etc. Once that is done you can use `arrows` as in

```
arrows(x0=0, y0=0, x1=1, y1=0 col = "black")
arrows(x0=0, y0=0, x1=.707, y1=.707, col = "red")
```

to form something such as

[image]